# How to compute the probability of a stochastic $X_t$ process to lie in a region $[x_0,x_1]$ during the interval $t\in[t_0,t_1]$.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I am working with a scalar stochastic process $X_t$ which satisfies some stochastic differential equation of the form
$$
dX_t = \mu(X_t,t)dt+\sigma(X_t,t)dB_t
$$
and for which I managed to compute a probability distribution $p(x,t)$ satisfying the corresponding Kolgomorov's backward equation:
$$
-\partial_t p(x,t) = \mu(x,t)\partial_x p(x,t)+\frac{1}{2}\sigma(x,t)^2\partial_x^2p(x,t)
$$
From there, given $t=t_0$ I know that I can compute the probability of $X_{t_0}$ to lie in a certain region using $p(x,t_0)$ as a probability distribution density. However, I am confused about what happens if I want to consider other options for $t$ other than a single value.

For example, I wonder if I can start answering questions such as computing the probability of $X_t$ being identically 0 for all $t\geq 0$, or (which I am more interested in) the probability of $X_t\in[x_0,x_1],\forall t\in[t_0,t_1]$ for given $x_0,x_1,t_0,t_1\in\mathbb{R}$. I cannot finish to understand how the information of $p(x,t)$ or the stochastic differential equation actually captures those probabilities.

EDIT: In case it helps, consider constant coefficients in the SDE and initial condition $X_0$ to be gaussian, such that $X_t$ is a guassian process. Even in this case, I am not sure how to approach the aforementioned questions.

Comment: Your question is stated in a very general fashion, but my first thought is to think about what kind of recurrence or equation the quantity you're studying might itself satisfy. For example, "the probability of $X_t$ being identically $0$ for all $t \geq 0$" could have a recurrence, if $X_t$ has the Markov property or something (or you take the limit as $t$ approaches $\infty$ of $X$ being identically zero on $[0,t]$, and figure out a recurrence for that quantity in terms of $t$). This kind of problem is not easy, so I would be excited to know if you have a more specific situation in mind.

Comment: Thanks! What if we assume $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are constant and $X_0$ is gaussian. Then, $X_t$ is a gaussian process, right? Can we answer those questions in this case? Im interested in the general case anyway (understanding how this info is embedded in $p(x,t$))

Comment: Ah, Gaussian process, then we should be able to make some kind of sweeping statement.  This is a good question.

Comment: Thanks! I added these details to the question in case it helps.

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot (and +1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing the probability distribution density is not enough to answer the questions you are interested in. Instead, you may write an equation for some quantity of interest.

For example, let us consider the probability that $X_t \in [a,b]$ for all $t\in [0,T]$. To write an equation, denote $\tau_{[a,b]} = \inf\{s: X_s\notin [a,b]\}\wedge T$ and define
$$
q(x,t) = \mathbb{P}(X_s\in [a,b]\ \forall s\in[t,T]\mid X_t = x) 
 = \mathbb{P}\big(\tau_{[a,b]}\ge T\mid X_t = x\big)\\
= \mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{1}_{\tau_{[a,b]}\ge T}\mid X_t = x] = \mathbb{E}\big[ g({X}_{\tau_{[a,b]}})\mid X_t = x\big],
$$
where $g(x) = \mathbb{1}_{(a,b)}(x)$. Despite $g$ is discontinuous, we can still write the boundary value problem for $q$:
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} q(x,t) + \mathcal L_{t,x} q(x,t) = 0,\quad & x\in (a,b), t<T;\\
q(x,T) = 1,& x \in (a,b);\\
q(a,t) = q(b,t) = 0, & t<T,
\end{cases}
$$
where $\mathcal L_{t,x} = \mu(x,t)\partial_x +\frac{1}{2}\sigma(x,t)^2\partial_x^2$ is the generator of $X$.

This boundary value problem is quite hard to solve in general, especially for time-dependent $\mu$ and $\sigma$. In homogeneous case, more or less explicit solutions for some particular cases (Brownian motion with or without drift, Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process) can be found in Borodin and Salminen's "Handbook".

Comment: Im ok with numerical solutions. I guess I can use them here for the BVP? Moreover, I dont understand how you got the BVP, but I guess the reference you provided might cover that, right? Thanks a lot!

Comment: A reference, huh... Any advanced text on stochastic analysis should do. Actually, this BVP is an immediate consequence of Dynkin's formula. I didn't mention in my answer that the diffusion should be regular enough (uniform ellipticity + mild regularity of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ should be enough).

Comment: Speaking of numerical solutions, you should be extremely careful with them, as they are likely to misbehave, since $g$ is discontinuous.